# Why isn't DictWriter working in my code?

Tags: python, csv

Using some help from the internet, I construct a generic function that extracts specific columns from a csv file and reads it to a dictionary, specified by the input **keys**.

```
import csv
def dict_filter(it, keys):
    for d in it:
        yield dict((k, d[k]) for k in keys)
```

Then I call this method later to write these columns into another CSV file using `DictReader`and `DictWriter`:

```
fieldnames = ["_STATE", "HEIGHT", "WEIGHT", "_BMI", "AGE", "CTYCODE", "IYEAR"]
source = open("data88.csv", 'r')
reader = csv.DictReader(source) 
result = open("aggregate_data.csv", 'w') 
writer = csv.DictWriter(result, fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore') 
for d in dict_filter(reader, fieldnames):
    if d['_STATE'] == "17" : 
         writer.writerow(str(d))
```

Here's the error I get in terminal:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

In TextWrangler:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): writer.writerow(str(d))
```

I've looked all over the internet and am not finding any relief. Why is `writerow` not working on my instance of DictWriter?

Comment: That's the entire error? That's surprising. There wasn't a line after it?

Comment: Yep, I'm running it in TextWrangler, and there wasn't any line after.

Comment: That edit explains a lot. Try changing the line to `writer.writerow(d)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

```
writer.writerow(str(d))
```

to

```
writer.writerow(d)
```